# Create separate report directory on each run using Selenium-Cucumber Maven

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, cucumber-junit, selenium-extent-report

I am using extent reporting to generate report files in selenium-cucumber . On each run, a report is generated by overwriting the previously generated report. How can we create separate report folders by appending timestamps on each run.

The POM file that i am using is given :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>selcuc</groupId>
  <artifactId>DemoEurasia</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
<version.cucumber>3.0.2</version.cucumber>
<timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
 <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
 <dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
<groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
<artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
<version>1.0.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId> 
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId> 
    <version>2.12.2</version> 
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```
<build>
    <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>          
            </configuration>
          </plugin> 

          <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.17</version>
    </plugin>                                
    </plugins>
</build>
```

It would be really helpful if you guys give an answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will generate a String object of current timestamp (you can change the format to whatever you like :

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
```

Now, wherever you are generating the extent report, you can pass this string inside your report name. Something like this:

```
extent = new ExtentReports (userDir +"\\test-output\\" + timeStamp + ".html", true);
```

**Bonus point:**

You can also add the feature name to your report for better accessibility. You can do that in your `@Before` hook like this:

```
@Before()
    public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario)
    {
        String fileName = scenario.getName() + "-" + timeStamp;
        extent = new ExtentReports (userDir + \\test-output\\" + fileName+ ".html", true);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this answer by updating TestRunnerTest.java as below: Please correct me

Comment: plugin={"com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"})
monochrome = true
public class TestRunnerTest{
public static String timeStamp=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
private static TestRunnerTest sharedInstance = new TestRunnerTest();
@AfterClass
public static void after() {Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("config/report.xml"));
ExtentReports  extent = new ExtentReports (userDir +"\\target\\" + timeStamp + "cucumber-reports/report.html", true);}

Comment: but i have a doubt that what we need to give as 'userDir' in this statement :  ExtentReports extent = new ExtentReports (userDir +"\\target\\" + timeStamp + "cucumber-reports/report.html", true);}
Also can you please explain each params ?? it will be very helpful for me as a beginner .

Comment: userDir is nothing but your directory where you want to store the report. You have to replace it with `new ExtentReports ("C:\\someFolder" + fileName + ".html", true); `

Comment: @Milu if my answer helped you, please accept my answer by clicking the hollow tick mark at the left of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple!!!!!!

Don't mention any folder path in plugin `com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter`.

Example :

```
plugin = { 
    "pretty", 
    "html:FeaturesReport",
    "html:target/site/cucumber-pretty",
    "json:target/cucumber.json",

    "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:",
},
```

1. run project and refresh it
2. check report will generate in default folder output/Run_with system time/report.html

**If you want to generate report in specified path with time stamp just follow  below steps.**

1. goto maven dependencies
2. search cucumber-extentsreport.jar
3. extend jar and select `com.cucumber.listener` package
4. copy entire code in `ExtentProperties` class
5. right on package and create new enum with name of `ExtentProperties`
6. then paste `ExtentProperties` class code in created enum
7. search below method

```
ExtentProperties() {
    this.reportPath = "output" + File.separator + "Run_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + File.separator + "report.html";
    this.projectName = "default";
}
```

8. and repalce with below code

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());

String userDir = System.getProperty("user.dir"); 

ExtentProperties() {
    this.reportPath = "Extent_Reports" + File.separator + "_" + timeStamp.replace(":","_").replace(".","_") + File.separator + "Execution report.html";
    this.projectName = "default";
}
```

9. run the project then refresh the project
10. check report will generate in specified path with name

Extent_Reports/_2020_06_16_19_14_07/Execution report.html

**Please comment if you have any questions**